# Не могу запустить программу в Clion

Tags: c, компиляция, clion

Сегодня поставил Clion, для теста решил написать простейшую программу на C, но при компиляции выдает ошибку:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   printf("asd");
   return 0;
}
```

> Error running 'untitled': Cannot run program "C:\Users\killy\CLionProjects\untitled\library.c" (in directory "E:\clion_projects"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 не является приложением Win32

Скажите пожалуйста, как можно исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Содержимое CMakeLists.txt покажите

Comment: `library.c` - это не программа, а текстовый файл с исходным кодом